# webapp2 with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, compatibility, webapp2

I use webapp2 with python 2.7 with or without googleAppEngine.
I'm now trying to use it with Python 3.3

I've used PIP to install webapp2
Install run with success but when I try to import webapp2 from IDLE gaves me the folowing error:

```
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import webapp2
    File "C:\Python3\lib\webapp2.py", line 571
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
```

I suspect it's a thing that must be updated in order to work with Python3...
?anybody done this already or should I wait for an updated version of webapp2
?is there any a beta version for Python 3 that we can access

Comment: App Engine doesn't run Python 3 so no effort has been made to make webapp2 work there (while it does have to run on 2.5); You could try to run 2to3 on it, but you certainly can't expect it to run without modifications.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like webapp2 is now compatible with Python3 from version `webapp2>=3.0.0b1`. This is still a "development" version - you have to specify that you want this version installed as:

`pip install webapp2>=3.0.0b1`

Hope it helps somebody that comes across this (old) question as I did.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, `webapp2` is *not* Python 3 compatible.

There is a [issue on Python 3](https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/issues/detail?id=40) in the issue tracker for the project, but there is next to *no* content in that issue. There does not appear to be any effort towards a port yet.

Comment: I've just visited and leave a comment, thanks for your info 

https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/issues/detail?id=40